# Error using 'Extract Binaries from Html' with new 2013 XSLT TBBs

Tags: templating, 2013, xslt

I am using the new out-of-the-box XSLT TBBs offered by Tridion 2013. When I use a DWT TBB to render my component content, and add the 'Extract Binaries from Html' TBB directly after it, everything works fine.

However if I use an XSLT TBB to output the identical HTML output, the 'Extract Binaries from Html' throws the following error:  `The item Output must have property TCMURI specified`.

Has anyone else seen this error? or have suggestions on what may be causing it?

Comment: I heard that XSLT template support on 2013 has been dropped. XSLT Mediator is part of 2013. I'm not sure how far is that true.

Comment: @SivaCharan - I am using the new 2013 XSLT Mediator - Not the old XSLT CTs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some digging, I decided to make a C# TBB to add the missing property as follows:

```
Item outputItem = package.GetByName("Output");
outputItem.Properties["BaseTCMURI"] = engine.PublishingContext.ResolvedItem.Template.Id;
package.PushItem("Output", outputItem );
```

After adding this between the XSLT TBB and the Extract Binaries TBB, everything works fine. From this I conclude that the 2013 XSLT Mediator is missing this line of code (which presumably is implemented in the DWT mediator. I plan to submit this as a bug to Customer Support.

Answer (score 4):

### Extract binaries from HTML

> It checks the `Output` item in the input package (containing HTML or XHTML) for references to Multimedia Components in the form of file names with relative paths. It retrieves the binary content of those Multimedia Components and adds them as binary streams to the package, and it replaces the filename references with TCM URI references in the output.
>
> *Note: By default, the template processes an item called `Output`. If you want to specify a different item to process, set the parameter Item name to identify the item to be processed.*

**<sub>*Source is taken from [SDLLiveContent](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL_Tridion_2013&lang=en-US#addHistory=true&filename=creatingTBBsAndAddingThemToCompoundTemplate_22.xml&docid=idheading-359771056&inner_id=&tid=&query=&scope=&resource=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocidheading-359771056)</sub>**

### Update:

When you use DWT TBB, it automatically creates a `Output` package and you have added the 'Extract Binaries from Html' TBB after DWT TBB. So it worked very well.

But when you use XSLT TBB, I feel either "`Output` package is not created" or "`Output` package is missed up the TCMURI references" which caused **"The item Output must have property TCMURI specified."** error

Comment: This does not explain why there is a difference between what happens when using different mediators to generate the HTML.

Comment: @ChrisSummers: I think, Output item doesn't contain TCM URI reference. Thats the reason I have posted this. I thought it will help you.